# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I've installed RVM successfully in Ubuntu 11.0. However when I'm up to the step where I execute:

rvm install 1.9.3 I get the following error(s).

```
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/fulvio/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /home/fulvio/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /home/fulvio/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /home/fulvio/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.log
Installing yaml to /home/fulvio/.rvm/usr
ERROR: Error running 'make install', please read /home/fulvio/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.install.log
```

I'm concerned about the "Error running 'make' and 'make install'.

Comment: What did you find in `make.log`?

Comment: @sarnold YAML library wasn't installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely missing some development library.  /home/fulvio/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.log should tell you which one.

Comment: Found the missing dev library and installed it. Thanks.